How can I scrape a blazor website with python
I've scraped quite a few websites and normally this hasn't been a big issue (those that use http requests with form data or json APIs). Now I stumbled upon one which has me absolutely stuck. After hours of analyzing it with chrome developer tools I determined that it:

uses websocktes
uses blazor (apparently a microsoft technology I've never heard of) for communication via those websockets

The problem is that all the messages that this blazor thing sends or receives via websockets are in binary format and it's entirely unclear what is going on. The only other thing I managed to find out regarding this that apparently something like SignalR is being used here.
Is it possible to scrape this website (I need to login and parse some data, although already the login happens via blazor) using python, how do I start understanding what those binary messages are?
Or is this a revolution and such sites are not scrapable?
Not sure how to proceed at all
enter image description here

Intercepting backend calls is not scraping. You didn't have to spend hours to find out what Blazor is or that it uses WebSockets. Websockets are a very popular way of sending notifications to clients, so you'll encounter the same problem with other SPAs, not just Blazor. So what are you actually trying to do, since you aren't doing scraping?

I need to log in and parse the screen after the login in order to read some data. How is this not scraping?

Again, you don't need to intercept the backend calls to do that. Just like any SPA, you can use Playwright or Selenium. Which means you're doing something else, not using a browser but some other unspecified package to emulate a browser. What are you using?

Do you want to "parse the screen" or "parse the html" ?  Different things. But basically, Blazor (without prerendering) is a Virtual-DOM based SPA. You should have had the same problems with for instance Angular or React sites.

Or perhaps any site that uses Webassembly. React and Angular SPAs use websockets too. A package that can retrieve the SPA's script and execute it wouldn't care about Websockets BUT if that package doesn't know about Webassembly, it won't work

I guess I was lucky to not have encountered those angular and react sites. Here I already have no idea how I log in, because it has a form and then after I input my credentials there it sends some binary message which I have no clue what it contains, so I already do not know how to log in programmatically.
Normally when scraping http sites I was sending manual http requests in python and parsing the html response or the api response to get the data.
Maybe selenium as you suggested...

You haven't explained what you're using yet. Beautifulsoup? Some other package? Your own custom code? If you haven't encountered Websockets before, check Mozilla's Websocket guide . Scraping SPA is tricky and there's no tool that can do everything. You can't expect that you'll be able to just ignore the UI and work with the HTTP calls. That's why libraries like Selenium, Playwright or Scrapy combined with Splash exist, to automate (possibly headless) browsers, allowing you to scrape the actual HTML.

Actually I think that you pointed to me to the right direction, I'm looking at Selenium so I just can actually have it treated like a webbrowser and don't care if it's websockets or not, so I'll just click buttons and input data into the fields and read the info from DOM. Sounds promising. Thanks
